# How to get JWT and Access Token oAuth for Facebook Login in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-access-token, jwt

I am implementing Facebook login in my android app, for that I need JWT and Access Token oAuth. What steps should follow to get Token.

Comment: visit this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Answer (score 2):

@rahul-kohli & I had a similar question for my application. We was a little concerned with security of storing facebook access tokens on android and decided against using the SDK. There were reports of phones being hacked for obtaining these access token left lying around by lazy android developers.

We figured it out with the help of [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.3).

We had a backend set up with django rest api framework. You should be getting your jwt tokens through a similar API. We use [this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/) for our work.

We used web views to make the call for facebook authentication & authorization. Check above link for exact URI to provide for the web view.

calling other class with the url for facebook by:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (LoginActivity.this, WebViewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("url",getString(R.string.facebook_auth_url) +"&" +getString(R.string.facebook_redirect_url));   
startActivity(intent);
```

This will prompt a facebook page to authenticate the user. On successful authentication, Facebook will pass an access code as a parameter attached to the redirect URI.

The following class calls the facebook url and then that url redirects you to the m.facbook~ url which further shows the facebook login and authentication page for the permissions.

It redirects you to your website i.e. the redirect url provided by you earlier. Further in django that auth code

```
package <your package name>;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import <YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME>.R;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String accessCode="";
    private String serverUrl ="http://<url>";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
        String url= getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
        System.out.println("url: " + url);

        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        webview =(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
        webview.loadUrl(url);
    }
    void serverPingJson() throws JSONException {
    // this function sends the access code to the API server to get the JWT token 
        String serverUrl= getString(R.string.api_url)+"authentication/sociallogin/social/jwt_user/facebook/";
        String sendMessage="{ \"clientId\" : \""+ getString(R.string.facebbok_client_id)+"\",\n" +
            "    \"code\" : \""+jwtToken+"\",\n" +
            "    \"redirectUri\" : \""+serverUrl+"\"\n" +
            "}";
        JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(sendMessage);
        JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, serverUrl,jsonObject,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    // You should see the JWT token in your response here
                    // extract the token and proceed from here on.
                    System.out.println("response 678: "+response.toString())
                    //Redirect to next section or page after you get your token as a reply.
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        Volley.newRequestQueue(getBaseContext()).add(postRequest);
    }

    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        //This class lets you get the access code
        //Once you authenticate you should get an access code from facebook
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            if(url.contains(serverUrl+"?code=")){
                accessCode=url.replace(serverUrl+"?code=","");
                try {
                    serverPingJson();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the official SDK?

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.4

Answer (score 0):

I'm also developing an app using Facebook login.
The official documentation is very useful as mentioned  Tobi.

Here is the code to get your access Token ( from the official doc )

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(
            AccessToken oldAccessToken,
            AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
                // Set the access token using 
                // currentAccessToken when it's loaded or set.
        }
    };
    // If the access token is available already assign it.
    accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
}
```

Comment: Author asks about exactly JWT token. Is this the same as usual access token?